# How to implement exponentiation of a rational number without nth root?

Tags: math, exponentiation, zoho

Its available for me only log(base "e"), sin, tan and sqrt (only square root) functions and the basic arithmetical operators (+ - * / mod). I have also the "e" constant.

I'm experimenting several problems with Deluge (zoho.com) for these restrictions. I must implement exponentiation of rational (fraction) bases and exponents.

Comment: Your own answer to your other question was "e^(Log(number)/index)". So what's wrong with "e^(Log(number)*exponent)"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating exponent exponentiation algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432075/floating-exponent-exponentiation-algorithm)

Comment: The prbolem is that I've discovered that I'm not able to use e^, because Deluge doesn't has a exp (e^) function. So, I cant' perform the algorithm.

Comment: You can use the Taylor series to compute `e^x`, though your fractions may explode in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you want to calculate `pow(A, B)`

Consider the representation of `B` in base 2:

```
B = b[n]   * pow(2, n    ) +
    b[n-1] * pow(2, n - 1) +
    ...
    b[2]   * pow(2, 2    ) +
    b[1]   * pow(2, 1    ) +
    b[0]   * pow(2, 0    ) +
    b[-1]  * pow(2, -1   ) +
    b[-2]  * pow(2, -2   ) +
    ...

 = sum(b[i] * pow(2, i))
```

where `b[x]` can be `0` or `1` and `pow(2, y)` is an integer power of two (i.e., `1`, `2`, `4`, `1/2`, `1/4`, `1/8`).

Then,

```
pow(A, B) = pow(A, sum(b[i] * pow(2, i)) = mul(pow(A, b[i] * pow(2, i)))
```

And so `pow(A, B)` can be calculated using only multiplications and square root operations

Comment: This assumes B is a diadic rational, or that its approximation using diadic rationals is accurate enough.  If B is represented as an ordered pair of integers (e.g., (1,3) for 1/3), this may not be appropriate.

Comment: @Josephine: IMO, in the context of programming, it is an acceptable assumption as it is the way computers represent numbers internally. If the OP wants to support other kind of numbers he should estate it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function F() that does e^x, where e is the constant, and x is any number, then you can do this: (a is base, b is exponent, ln is log-e)

a^b = F(b * ln(a))

If you don't have F() that does e^x, then it gets trickier. If your exponent (b) is rational, then you should be able to find integers m and n so that b = m/n, using a loop of some sort. Once you have m and n, you make another loop which multiples a by itself m times to get a^m, then multiples a by itself n times to get a^n, then divide a^m/a^n to get a^(m/n), which is a^b.

Comment: a^m/a^n = a^(m-n), not a^(m/n).

Comment: You're right. I haven't a F() function (like exp()) to do the hard work for me, unfortunately. If so, I should solve the problem wiht the nth root formula. Would you give me an example of the tricky way to do the solution? I'm not shure if I've understood. Supose 5^(0,5): its equivalent 5^(1/2) => 5/25 => 0.2. But the correct answer is 2.2360. Thanks!